# Posting questions by email?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, email, posting

I want to be able to ask a question by sending an email to some special email address for Stack Overflow. I have found this convenient in other situations like Google Groups, blogging, and Facebook walls, and it seems that technically it shouldn't be too hard to do.

Does this feature exist already? I'm kind of afraid to ask for features as some of them get downvoted simply since users think they are not neccessary (and not because the post is bad).

Comment: Downvotes on meta indicated disagreement. People who are downvoting this because they think the feature is not necessary are doing exactly what they're supposed to do.

Comment: This is a duplicate, but I can't find the duplicate off hand. To summarize, we don't want this feature. The kind of fire-and-forget behaviour this would encourage is not something we would like to see on Stack Overflow. You're expected to research your question before posting them, at the very least on Stack Overflow so that you don't post duplicates.

Comment: One other issue I don't see mentioned is that the StackOverflow browser offers a preview of your Markdown formatted question (essential if you include code, or something like a list). A post sent by email wouldn't have this check, and the asker probably wouldn't see the post for a while (leaving others to fix the formatting if he made a mistake).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This function does not, as yet, exist in Stack Overflow. Nor can I imagine it ever will, mainly because I can't see any advantages to the submit-by-email approach.

I do, however, see at least one large disadvantage to such a system in that when you present a question we expect it to be well-researched and, for research purposes, your browser is the better environment and it's impossible, I'd imagine, to search a Stack Exchange site from within your email client (so you increase the odds of posting a duplicate question).

Also, given the ability to ask, and use, Stack Exchange from a mobile browser (smartphone, tablet, etc) I can't see what benefit this feature would add to the site/network.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess one outcome is that we will see much more duplicates. That's not a good outcome - I agree.

Comment: Also, tagging - how would you apply the right tags in an E-Mail?

Comment: It remains a fairly terrible idea to put into practice, but I could see the subject-line of an email being analogous to tagging; though I think it would lead to further problems (accidental typos leading to wrong or new (or *both*) tags being created being only the most obvious).