# Can I somehow stop the negative reputation on a feature request that keeps getting downvoted

Tags: discussion, down-votes, asking-questions, deleted-questions

I just asked for a feature and apparently it wasn't a good idea. After reading all the responses I tend to agree with that.
During this process I had my reputation decreased several times and I was wondering if there is a way to take that back or at least stop that since it seems to keep getting downvoted.

Comment: Nope. And don't worry about it. Meta rep doesn't mean a thing.

Comment: As of now, after another few downvotes you'll be at 1 reputation and that will prevent you losing any more.  Really though, even with only 1 rep you can still ask and answer questions here and doing so will likely bring your rep right back up if that's a concern.

Comment: [Comparatively](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146440/email-submission-for-high-enough-ranked-users), you're still doing pretty well.

Comment: Keep in mind that 1 upvote == 5 reputation whereas 1 downvote == -2 reputation. So even a controversial post can still leave you with positive gains. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to stop your feature request from getting more downvotes is to ask for it to be deleted (by flagging it for moderation attention). However it won't be surprising if your request is denied, we generally don't like deleting open questions with upvoted answers, someone spend some time to give you a good answer and there's absolutely no reason for their effort to go to waste.

Another way would be for you to ask for the question to be disassociated from your account. A valid option, but a bit extreme, especially for a trivial reason like evading downvotes. If you decide you want your name removed from the question, you should follow the process outlined in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96746/162704):

> If you would like to have your name removed from our use of the post, you can flag it for moderator attention. Moderators do not have the ability to change the ownership of the message, but they can bring it to the attention of a developer who may be able to reassign ownership to the Community user or some other "anonymous" entity.

The better approach here is to stop worrying about Meta reputation, it's the most worthless metric there is. You are still very new to the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/), when you discover the other 80+ sites you'll find out that Meta Stack Overflow is the *only* Meta site in the network that has reputation, and that's mostly a relic of the past. On all other Metas the displayed reputation is your main site reputation, and voting on Meta posts doesn't affect it.

In your [earlier question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149367/post-question-by-email) you mention:

> I'm kind of afraid to ask for features as some of them get downvoted simply since users think they are not neccessary (and not because the post is bad)

Don't be afraid, [voting on Meta is a bit different](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) than on the main site:

> #### Are upvotes and downvotes different on meta?
>
> Voting here works a bit differently from other Stack Exchange sites. On Meta Stack Overflow, voting is often used to express agreement or disagreement, not to point out a lack of quality or helpfulness. Please don't be concerned if you receive downvotes – members of the community may simply disagree with your bug, feature request, support issue, or the nature of the discussion.

We do downvote features that we don't think are necessary, and it's a confusing inconsistency, but it really shouldn't discourage you from sharing your ideas, at the end of the day reputation on both the Meta and the main site is just an integer on a database somewhere.

Comment: I wonder if asking for disassociation is an option. IIRC, that is a right guaranteed by the the cc-wiki license.

Comment: @Mysticial That's certainly an option.

Comment: @Mysticial I guess requesting disassociation is an option, but I have no idea if Stack Exchange will honour it. AFAIK it's a manual process, and albeit being a perhaps valid option, I wouldn't really want to encourage it if there isn't a very good reason for it (and evading downvotes isn't, imho).

Comment: @AnnaLear Adding it to the answer then.

Comment: @YannisRizos We are obligated to honour disassociation requests. It's a part of our content license.

Comment: @mystical note that while the request *must* be honored, if it was done often (and it wouldn't take many at all for us to detect this, think low single digits) for the purpose of avoiding downvotes, then we'd probably issue a suspension for abusing the system like this.  After all, it's easier for us to stop this at the source.  Dissociation is *not* intended for this purpose.

Comment: @casperOne I'd consider it less of a problem on MSO, although even here if done all the time it'd certainly raise a few eyebrows.

Comment: I notice that the mouseover texts on the upvote/downvote buttons are *still* inconsistent with 'voting on Meta is a bit different'.

Answer (score 3):

As [Yannis notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149382/can-i-somehow-stop-the-negative-reputation-on-a-feature-request-that-keeps-getti/149413#149413), you really shouldn't worry too much about MSO reputation. It's fairly meaningless, and extremely easy to come by if you need some: just help a few people learn how the sites work.

If a particular question becomes a problem for you somehow, use the Contact Us link found at the bottom of every page to let us know, and we'll see what we can do to resolve it.