# Possible to ask a question by e-mail?

Tags: feature-request, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [post question by email](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149367/post-question-by-email)

Can I ask my questions by sending an email?

I can post to my Blogger stream using a "key" embedded in the address or body of the e-mail, could I in any way post on StackOverflow using the same system?

Comment: It would be helpful if you described what benefit you felt this would provide.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably not a good idea. An essential part of asking a question is checking that it hasn't been asked before. If you're not posting your question through your browser, you're probably not checking for dupes either.

Comment: "checking for dupes" === "researching your problem"... I know it's just semantics but I feel there are negative connotations with the term "dupe". One does not "check for dupes" so much as they try to find an answer to their problem.

Comment: Doesn't have absolutely anything to do with the pre-check phase? Say I want to post code: using mutt and its powerful copy/paste is only of help. Vim is superior to the web interface. Why make this strange assumption of checks and dups?

Comment: All I'm saying is that when you're posting a question, you want to have as much context available as possible (such as, "has this been asked before") in order to help you post a *good* question. Without using the website itself, you loose a lot of valuable context.

Comment: @Robottinosino: the thing you need to remember is that for each feature you add to the system to make life easier for "good" users, there's ten "evil" users out there waiting to use it for their own purposes. If such a thing is implemented, *you* might undertake due diligence before using it (I'll have to take you at your word on that), but I guarantee there will be others (probably a majority) who wont.